# How get MySql distinct (different) values in ASC order

Tags: mysql

I'm having table

like this

```
--------------------------------------------
id    size    title              priority
---------------------------------------------
1       4      sample title1        2
2       2      sample title2        2
3       3      sample title3        1
4       1      sample title4        2
5       2      sample title5        1
6       3      sample title6        2
7       1      sample title7        1
8       4      sample title8        1
-------------------------------------------
```

I want a query to get output like below:

```
--------------------------------------------
id    size    title              priority
---------------------------------------------
7       1      sample title7        1
5       2      sample title5        1
3       3      sample title3        1
8       4      sample title8        1
4       1      sample title4        2
2       2      sample title2        2
6       3      sample title6        2
1       4      sample title1        2


-------------------------------------------
```

So, I want Different size values in ascending order also check priority in ascending order.

Comment: `ORDER BY priority, size` ?

Answer (score 1):

As **Giorgos Betsos** mentioned:

```
SELECT * FROM table_ ORDER BY priority, size  ASC;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65402/4)